# Trying to create a guess my letter code. How do I incorporate the case where the input char from the user equals my letter?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that compares the letter a user inputs to my letter. If the letters are the same, the program should say that they are the same, then terminate. If they are not the same, then the user should be prompted to enter another character until they guess it correctly.

I have tried nesting an if statement and nesting a while loop to achieve the case where the letters are equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char myLetter = 'a';

    printf("insert a char:");

    char userLetter;

    scanf("%1s", &userLetter);

    while (userLetter !=  myLetter)
    {
        printf("%c does not match mine, try again:", userLetter);

        scanf("%1s", &userLetter);
    }

    while (userLetter == myLetter)
    {
        printf("char matches! program will terminate now. ");

        break;
    }
}
```

expected:

```
insert a char:h
h does not match mine, try again:j
j does not match mine, try again:g
g does not match mine, try again:f
f does not match mine, try again:a
char matches! program will terminate now.
```

actual:

```
insert a char:h
h does not match mine, try again:j
j does not match mine, try again:g
g does not match mine, try again:f
f does not match mine, try again:a
a does not match mine, try again:a does not match mine, try again:^C
```

Comment: A string '%s' is not the same as a char '%c'

Comment: Yeah, I had an issue with using '%c' . Every time I entered a character, it would include the enter input, thus it would run the loop twice until asking me for a new character.

Comment: When reading from a user input, you usually want to read a whole line, including the line terminator, and then extract the part that you want.

Comment: 1. I switched scanf("%1s", &userLetter); to scanf(" %c", &userLetter); noting the space. This terminated the program after each input.

Comment: 2. I switched the user input to a string and did conditionals based on the first character in the string entered and my character (compared the values). This gave me the same result as I had with the above program and did not evaluate the second while loop when userLetter == myLetter.

Comment: I changed both xing

Comment: You don't need the second `while` loop. If you get out of the first loop, it means that the char matches.

Comment: I took out the second while loop and left the printf statement. I guess the issue is that I cannot get out of the first loop.

Comment: It also works for me when I change the scanf pattern.

Comment: Xing, your comment about changing the scanf pattern worked after trying it again with the help from Barmar. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format operator for reading a single character is `%c`, not `%1s`. The latter reads a single character, but writes it into a null-terminated string, so it will write a null byte outside the `userLetter` variable, which causes undefined behavior.

You should put a space before the operator to make `scanf` skip over whitespace before reading the character. This is needed to make it ignore the newline after each response.

You should also turn off output buffering or flush the buffer after each prompt, since they don't end with a newline.

There's no need for the `while` loop at the end, since you don't get out of the first loop until the characters match.

This is a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char myLetter = 'a';

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("insert a char:");

    char userLetter;
    scanf(" %c", &userLetter);

    while (userLetter !=  myLetter)
    {
        printf("%c does not match mine, try again:", userLetter);
        scanf(" %c", &userLetter);
    }

    printf("char matches! program will terminate now.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing 2 char why don't you get user letter with `scanf("%c", userLetter)` and then you can compare them with `=` or `!=` operator. If you are getting input expecting a string value, then I suggest you to declare `userLetter` like this:

```
char* userLetter[1];
```

and then use scanf the way you did in your code BUT you have to compare the strings with `strcmp` function.

Comment: There are several errors in this answer. It should be `&userLetter`, and you need a space before `%c`. If you declare it as an array, the element type should be `char`, not `char*`, and it needs to be at least `[2]` to allow room for the null terminator.

Comment: Hi! I checked your answers and questions on all the sites where you are active. I think you are *good*, it is very well visible on your posts. The problem is that your writing style creates a bad first impression. The problem is that saying this to new users is not allowed: *"I is always uppercase in English, I hate if you write "i", so I vote you down"*. But actually doing it is okay. And, honestly, this is really one of the first thing anybody learns on his first English courses in his life. So, please, please, please, [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).